# Add a warning icon to the TextBox when validation

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I want to validate a textbox if something is wrong. The idea is if something is wrong than the next TextBox should have a warning image.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Age, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Placeholder for the TextBox itself -->
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="textBox"/>
                <image source="some-Image.png" width="20" Height="20" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</TextBox>
```

But the thing is the image is not showing, it only shows the border of the icon.
Am I using `AdornedElementPlaceholder` correctly?

Comment: why you don't doing thin in code it's very easy with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested solution that works and displays the image when error occurs:

```
<TextBox BorderThickness="0.8">
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                <Image Source="Image.jpg" Width="20" Height="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="ValidationTest" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validation:IntegerValidationRule ValidationStep="CommittedValue" Min="1" Max="99999999"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And here is the validation rule that I have used for this example:

```
public class IntegerValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    private int _min = int.MinValue;
    private int _max = int.MaxValue;
    private string _fieldName = "Field";
    private string _customMessage = String.Empty;

    public int Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set { _min = value; }
    }

    public int Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set { _max = value; }
    }

    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return _fieldName; }
        set { _fieldName = value; }
    }

    public string CustomMessage
    {
        get { return _customMessage; }
        set { _customMessage = value; }
    }


    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int num = 0;

        var val = (value as BindingExpression).DataItem;

        if (!int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out num))
            return new ValidationResult(false, $"{FieldName} must contain an integer value.");

        if (num < Min || num > Max)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomMessage))
                return new ValidationResult(false, CustomMessage);


            return new ValidationResult(false, $"{FieldName} must be between {Min} and {Max}.");
        }

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

Which is just modified example from [MSDN Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation)
**Some notes:**
You didn't provide the validation rule so I am assuming it works as expected and produces valid validation result.
The Binding of your `TextBox.Text` property doesn't include the Validation rule.